# Getting type of an abstract base class from within the class

Tags: .net, vb.net, abstract-class, gettype

Right. This may be trivial, but I'm stuck. Consider the following line:

```
Dim x As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Me)
```

This doesn't compile. It tells me it cannot convert from `SomeClass` to `System.Type`. I tried it with `GetType(Me)` too, but that also doesn't compile. It does compile with `GetType(SomeClass)`, but I don't want to use that, becuz `SomeClass` is an abstract base class and I want the above line to create a serializer of specific child type for each of its children. (The above line is part of one of the functions of the base class that children do not override).

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I need to use `Me.GetType()` and not `GetType(Me)`.